# What is a paper engineer?

Tags: print-production

Recently I've wanted to get into making a pop-up book for kids and upon my research I've seen it mentioned the pre-production process starting with a paper engineer. Since this question wasn't on the site and I think it falls under the production process I thought it might be an interesting question. What is a paper engineer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of books out there with related titles:

Paper Engineering for Pop-up Books and Cards - by Mark Hiner

Paper Engineering and Pop-ups For Dummies - by Rob Ives

And there is a STEM engineering teaching resource website which has a section on Paper Engineering in the specific context of popups:

https://www.teachengineering.org/activities/view/cub_art_lesson01_activity2

And there's a site dedicated to popups in which there are listings for authors & paper engineers:

https://www.bestpopupbooks.com/pop-up-book-authors/

Which taken in concert lead me to believe that there's a recognised sub-branch of paper engineering which is specific to folding and popup paper products.

hope that helps.